# How to ignore Null values at the end of a string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, nul

I have a column nse_credit_rating with datatype `VARCHAR2(18)`.
It contains values of form `189.00-250.00`.
But some records have null values at the end of the string i.e even if the data relevant to me is of length 13 (`189.00-250.00`) but `length(nse_credit_rating)` returns 17 as output i.e there are 4 null values at the end.

Main issue occurs when I have to use `to_number` on this column, it returns "ORA-1722 invalid number" since it contains null.

Is there a way I can get the sub string before the occurrence of NULL values? 
I even took the output of `dump(nse_credit_rating)`.

```
SELECT dump(nse_credit_rating),nse_symbol 
FROM nse_security_master 
where nse_series='EQ'
  and nse_symbol like 'ARVIND' 
  and nse_series='EQ'
```

Output:

```
Typ=1 Len=17: 51,54,55,46,48,48,45,52,52,56,46,53,48,0,0,0,0
```

Here 0 is the ascii for NULL.

```
SELECT (nse_credit_rating),nse_symbol 
FROM nse_security_master 
where nse_series='EQ'
and nse_symbol like 'ARVIND' 
and nse_series='EQ'
```

Output:

```
367.00-448.50
```

I tried using `ascii(substr(nse_credit_rating,-1,1))` but this only works when I know that only one character in the end would be Null. But there could be any number of characters having NULL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rtrim()` to remove characters from the end of a string:

```
SELECT rtrim(nse_credit_rating, chr(0)) as nse_credit_rating
      ,nse_symbol 
FROM nse_security_master 
where nse_series='EQ'
and nse_symbol like 'ARVIND' 
and nse_series='EQ'
```

This is covered in the Oracle SQL documentation. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/RTRIM.html#GUID-95A7DAFB-F7AB-48F4-BE24-64B3C7A840AA). Oracle also supports the standard SQL `trim()` function but that is slightly more verbose:

```
SELECT trim(trailing chr(0) from nse_credit_rating) as nse_credit_rating
       , nse_symbol 
FROM nse_security_master 
where nse_series='EQ'
and nse_symbol like 'ARVIND' 
and nse_series='EQ'
```

> Can you tell me what chr(0) does here?

`chr()` is a function for turning ASCII numbers into characters. So `chr(0)` gives us ASCII null.

Comment: thanks , this is returning correct length .Can you tell me what chr(0) does here?

Answer (score -2):

The simple way is to use the trim function. Detailed info at below link
https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreftrimfunc.html

or use the [rtrim](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/RTRIM.html) directly.

Comment: it is a common function.. the aim here was to point in right direction.. but added another link for this specific case.

Comment: Answers which just link to other places are not good answers. A good answer stands on its own, without the need for links. (Although links are a fine way of supplementing an answer or providing more information.)

Comment: using rtrim directly doesn't solve the problem ,but as @APC mentioned rtrim(nse_credit_rating,chr(0)) gets the result.

Comment: I got your point of having an answer to stand on its own and agree to it. But I generally believe in " teach a man to fish approach" . Explore more, try out and learn few extra things out of it. It is just a different viewpoint.  :)

Comment: *" It is just a different viewpoint."* Actually it isn't. StackOverflow has well-established conventions regarding what is and what isn't a good answer. Link only answers are definitely Not Good Answers. Please read [this Meta response to understand why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/133829).

Comment: Great APC.. thanks for the info of meta. Will surely keep this in mind. :)